# How to list processes attached to a shared memory segment in linux?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, shared

How do I determine what process is attached to a shared memory segment?

```
awagner@tree:/home/awagner$ ipcs -m

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      
0x00000000 0          root       777        102400     1                       
0x00000000 32769      root       774        96         1          dest         
0x00000000 98306      awagner    600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 131075     awagner    600        393216     2          dest
```

i.e. how do I figure out which two processes are attached to shmid 98306?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with the standard tools. You can use `ipcs -mp` to get the process ID of the *last* process to attach/detach but I'm not aware of how to get *all* attached processes with `ipcs`.

With a two-process-attached segment, assuming they both *stayed* attached, you can possibly figure out from the creator PID `cpid` and last-attached PID `lpid` which are the two processes but that won't scale to more than two processes so its usefulness is limited.

The `cat /proc/sysvipc/shm` method seems similarly limited but I believe there's a way to do it with other parts of the `/proc` filesystem, as shown below:

When I do a `grep` on the `procfs` maps for all processes, I get entries containing lines for the `cpid` and `lpid` processes.

For example, I get the following shared memory segment from `ipcs -m`:

```
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      
0x00000000 123456     pax        600        1024       2          dest
```

and, from `ipcs -mp`, the `cpid` is 3956 and the `lpid` is 9999 for that given shared memory segment (123456).

Then, with the command `grep 123456 /proc/*/maps`, I see:

```
/proc/3956/maps: blah blah blah 123456 /SYSV000000 (deleted)
/proc/9999/maps: blah blah blah 123456 /SYSV000000 (deleted)
```

So there *is* a way to get the processes that attached to it. I'm pretty certain that the `dest` status and `(deleted)` indicator are because the creator has marked the segment for destruction once the final detach occurs, not that it's already been destroyed.

So, by scanning of the `/proc/*/maps` "files", you should be able to discover which PIDs are currently attached to a given segment.

Comment: Unix semantics allow to delete files/objects that are still in use. That means: You can delete files which are still open. So the file name is deleted but the file object is still there, once the last file handle is closed there is no more reference to the file and it is deleted. The same goes for shared memory objects in state "(deleted)". Those are still there but no longer accessible from new processes.

Answer (score 25):

given your example above - to find processes attached to shmid 98306

```
lsof | egrep "98306|COMMAND"
```

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a tool called who_attach_shm.pl, it parses /proc/[pid]/maps to get the information. 
you can download it from [github](https://github.com/curu/linuxplayer/blob/master/scripts/who_attach_shm.pl)

sample output:

```
shm attach process list, group by shm key
##################################################################

0x2d5feab4:    /home/curu/mem_dumper /home/curu/playd
0x4e47fc6c:    /home/curu/playd
0x77da6cfe:    /home/curu/mem_dumper /home/curu/playd /home/curu/scand

##################################################################
process shm usage
##################################################################
/home/curu/mem_dumper [2]:    0x2d5feab4 0x77da6cfe
/home/curu/playd [3]:    0x2d5feab4 0x4e47fc6c 0x77da6cfe
/home/curu/scand [1]:    0x77da6cfe
```

Comment: Dear Jacuro,  please provide the solution in this forum. The problem with links is, that they might out-date for various reasons.

Comment: @Trinimon, got it, I will provide a link to download the script instead.

Comment: -1 for failing to provide the solution in the answer after being told why it's important

Comment: The -1's seem quite negative - the code is still there many months on...

If the solution had been to "use Linux" - would you still require him to "include the source code in the answer" ?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone is interest only in what kind of process created the shared moeries, call

```
ls -l /dev/shm
```

It lists the names that are associated with the shared memories - at least on Ubuntu. Usually the names are quite telling.

Answer (score -2):

Use `ipcs -a`: it gives detailed information of all resources [semaphore, shared-memory etc]

Here is the image of the output:

[image]

Comment: You could copy the images contents to your answer.

Comment: I meant you could copy the *text* contents, which requires no reputation at all. It's a screenshot of text-only contents. You could put it in a code/quote block.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.  As the screenshot shows there is no information about what processes are attached to each block